pyspark some task failed but retry successfully, however, the responding parquet file did not wrote into the result table path
I run a pyspark job, the job stopped sucessfully, but when i check the result, i found that partial data seemed missing. then i check the log, here is some thing i found:

error inside log file

TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 549) (worker executor 1): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.taskFailedWhileWritingRowsError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:500)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:324)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$16(FileFormatWriter.scala:229)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] - Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: xxxxx/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202411281735309015966430992825558_0005_m_000007_549/dt=2024-11-19/region=br/part-00007-996f4f11-c9b2-4552-8b56-c6dfbba5c4b8.c000.snappy.parquet: not found
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at io.juicefs.JuiceFileSystemImpl.error(JuiceFileSystemImpl.java:196)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at io.juicefs.JuiceFileSystemImpl.access$500(JuiceFileSystemImpl.java:73)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at io.juicefs.JuiceFileSystemImpl$FSOutputStream.close(JuiceFileSystemImpl.java:1002)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:159)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:72)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream.close(FSDataOutputStream.java:101)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopPositionOutputStream.close(HadoopPositionOutputStream.java:64)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.end(ParquetFileWriter.java:1106)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.InternalParquetRecordWriter.close(InternalParquetRecordWriter.java:132)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordWriter.close(ParquetRecordWriter.java:164)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.close(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:75)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseCurrentWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:65)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.releaseResources(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:87)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:117)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:308)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1496)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -  ... 9 more
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] -
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] - 24/11/28 17:35:34 INFO [dispatcher-CoarseGrainedScheduler] TaskSetManager: Starting task 7.1 in stage 5.0 (TID 552) (worker-4, executor 8, partition 7, PROCESS_LOCAL, 4466 bytes) taskResourceAssignments Map()
[2024-11-28, 17:35:34 CST] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - 2024-11-28 17:35:34 - INFO - root - __init__.py:__execute_command:197 - [28755] - 


then i review the job execution detail on spakr web gui. from the above log we can know that #549 task failed at the first time, then spark restart #552 task the recompute and it run successfuly.


however, when i checked the path of result table, i did find the one parquet file is missing


Finally I try to run the my code again, and this time the result is correct.
According to my observation, this problem happens intermittently.
python version: 3.6
spark version: 3.2.0
This borders me because i am not able to know if the job actually run successfully or not

what is your input code ? maybe you implemented an iterator, consumed it the first time at fail, but when retrying since your iterator is fully consumed you don't have any data left to write

my code is like:  spark.sql("select * from table1").rdd.map(my_map_function()).insert("table2"), i dont think i had implemented any iterator

the error states that a file from input source wasn't found ... part-00007-996f4f11-c9b2-4552-8b56-c6dfbba5c4b8.c000.snappy.parquet: not found. it could be that some process was writing/overwriting your input source while your process was reading it, and your read process couldn't find a file that was noted from metadata
